# Error in Eclipse IDE while starting a project

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, jakarta-ee

i have trouble while opeing eclipse like "location of android sdk has not been setup in the preference". what i have to do for this error in eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

How to update your ADT to the latest version:

1. In Eclipse go to Help ---> Install New Software ---> Add ---> Add Repository
2. Write the Name: ADT (as you want) and Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
3. After loading some time, you will get Developer Tools and NDK Plugins
4. Check both if you want to use NDK in the future, or check Developer Tool only
5. Click <kbd>Next</kbd>
6. <kbd>Finish</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Goto Window--->Preferences .It will show a prompt dialogue like this

[image]

Browse the path of your SDK